# How do I clone an object with virtual navigational properties in it, using memberWiseClone in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have tried to clone an object using `memberWiseClone()`. It will clone all the value type properties successfully, but will not clone the reference type properties.

The class I'm trying to clone.

```cs
    public class Document
    {
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

        public int DocumentManagerId { get; set; }

        public virtual User DocumentManager { get; set; }

        public Document ShallowCopy()
        {
            return (Document)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

Getting all the correct values for `OwnerId` and `DocumentManagerId` except `DocumentManager`

`shallowCopy()`is called in my service class update method.(Keeping the state of previous document to log after the document is actually updated)

```cs
var document = await this.dbContext.Documents.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == documentDto.id);
var prevDocument = document.ShallowCopy();
```

Im getting the correct result for `document.DocumentManager` while not getting it for `prevDocument.DocumentManager`. Therefore, this should not be due to any configurations in entity mapping. I wanna know why the virtual object throws an exception when memberWiseCloning.

[image: Exception for documentManager property]

**Workaround used at the moment**

I have returned a new instances of both the objects with values manually mapped. 
Also i know i can go for deep cloning by serializing the value to memory stream. But i prefer if i can find a better way from `memberWiseClone` approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, there is a great post about deep cloning with you can find pros and cons of each approach. Did you check it? You can consider "copy constructor" approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: Hi @anilcemsimsek , yeah I've read that. Serializing will work, i wanna know why the virtual object throws an exception when `memberWiseCloning`. If I use the copy constructor approach, my inner object will change if its values are updated afterwards due to reference type.

Comment: @Thanks for clarifying the question.